# I dont know how to make a "const unsigned float&"

Tags: c++, constants, unsigned

I have this:

```
const unsigned float& distanceTo(const Point2D&){...}
```

but VS2013 says me that I have an invalid combination of type specifiers, how I must put the specifiers to return a constant reference to an unsigned float?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no unsigned floats. Just use `float` (or `const float&`).

Comment: I bet the OP really wants a `float`, not a reference to one. (And that he'd be better of with `double`, but that's a different story.)

Comment: That could very well be, agreed.